# How to plot data by counties?

Tags: plotting, geography

I'd like to plot county data as in [this D3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606):

[image]

Is there a way to do this with GeoGraphics, or at least to get path polygons per county and then plot them with different colors?

The first thing I tried was [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95162/how-to-make-geometric-intersection-faster-for-geographic-borders) which didn't work. Here's a snippet of my data:

```
(*county    value*)
49005   0.5742412852924035
49007   0.8317715755644481
49009   0.5453979492171142
49011   0.28254890319856485
49013   0.7479376357589627
49015   0.18711805968098272
49017   0.7457292949804695
49019   0.567573145972929
49021   0.16246935549286112
49023   0.9195138046651179
49025   0.4367034052124463
49027   0.6982473831931622
49029   0.8338046457979154
49031   0.9912431029895752
49033   0.7835820925255039
49035   0.1239835744258424
49037   0.6332753189833022
49039   0.1020405619672482
49041   0.6598660862197654
49043   0.292093295985822
```

Sadly these are missing:

```
EntityValue[
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"AbbevilleCounty", "SouthCarolina",
    "UnitedStates"}], 
 EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "FIPSCode"]]
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Updated text

I made a tutorial out of this answer and [posted it on Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1076067). It's slightly different, and may be worth to check out.

### Data from Wolfram Knowledgebase

The most straightforward way to plot data about counties is to use the built-in county entities and `GeoRegionValuePlot`.

```
counties = Cases[
   EntityList@Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Country" -> Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]}],
   Entity[_, {_, _, _}] (* separates states from counties *)
   ];

GeoRegionValuePlot[counties -> "ForeignBornFraction"]
```

[image: US county region value plot]

Here `ForeignBornFraction` is an entity property to adminstrative divisions.

### Creating a US county entity store

Wouldn't it be nice if we could visualize our own data like this?

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[counties -> "CustomUnemploymentData"]
```

In the just released *Mathematica* 11 we can achieve that goal with entity stores. Since the built-in county entities don't have county FIPS codes and we need FIPS codes to correlate the entities with our data, I'll take the FIPS codes that JasonB shared in his answer, and make my own entity system.

```
fipsRules = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/YSsKAbjn"]; (* JasonB's FIPS codes file, see his answer for details. *)
testdata = Rest@Import["https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4060606/raw/25385f68a3be5c9dbe36af27fc2498fb2aab6bc0/unemployment.tsv", "TSV"];

getEntity[fipsRules_][{fips_, unemployment_}] := 
 With[{entity = (IntegerString[fips] /. fipsRules)}, 
  If[MatchQ[entity, _String],
   Nothing, (* If the FIPS code does not exist in fipsRules *)
   getEntityIdentifier[entity] -> <|
     "Label" -> Style[entity["Name"], Bold],
     "ParentEntity" -> entity,
     "FIPSCode" -> fips,
     "Unemployment" -> unemployment
     |>
   ]]

getEntityIdentifier[Entity[_, {county_, state_, country___}]] := county <> "-" <> state
getEntityIdentifier[Entity[_, {"DistrictOfColumbia", _}]] := "DistrictOfColumbia"

countyEntities = Apply[Association, getEntity[fipsRules] /@ testdata];
```

So far we've imported both the unemployment data and the FIPS codes and used that to create an `Association` in the form dictated by `EntityStore`. Each entity in our custom entity store has the properties `ParentEntity`, `FIPSCode` and `Unemployment`. `Label` is also present, and is used for presentation.

`ParentEntity` is the built-in county entity and I will use that and computed properties to effect a sort of inheritance.

```
store = EntityStore["USCounty" -> <|
     "Entities" -> countyEntities,
     "Properties" -> <|
       "ParentEntity" -> <|
         "Label" -> "Parent entity"
         |>,
       "FIPSCode" -> <|
         "Label" -> "County FIPS code"
         |>,
       "Polygon" -> <|
         "DefaultFunction" -> (#["ParentEntity"]["Polygon"] &),
         "Label" -> "Polygon"
         |>,
       "Position" -> <|
         "DefaultFunction" -> (#["ParentEntity"]["Position"] &),
         "Label" -> "Position"
         |>,
       "Latitude" -> <|
         "DefaultFunction" -> (#["ParentEntity"]["Latitude"] &),
         "Label" -> "Latitude"
         |>,
       "Longitude" -> <|
         "DefaultFunction" -> (#["ParentEntity"]["Longitude"] &),
         "Label" -> "Longitude"
         |>,
       "HasPolygon" -> <|
         "DefaultFunction" -> (#["ParentEntity"]["HasPolygon"] &),
         "Label" -> "Has polygon?"
         |>,
       "Name" -> <|
         "DefaultFunction" -> (#["ParentEntity"]["Name"] &),
         "Label" -> "Name"
         |>
       |>,
     "EntityClasses" -> <|
       "Alaska" -> <|
         "Entities" -> ("ParentEntity" -> (MatchQ[#, Entity[_, {_, "Alaska", _}]] &)),
         "Label" -> Style["Alaska", Bold]
         |>,
       "Hawaii" -> <|
         "Entities" -> ("ParentEntity" -> (MatchQ[#, Entity[_, {_, "Hawaii", _}]] &)),
         "Label" -> Style["Hawaii", Bold]
         |>,
       "Mainland" -> <|
         "Entities" -> ("ParentEntity" -> (MatchQ[#, Entity[_, {_, Except["Alaska" | "Hawaii"], _}]] &)),
         "Label" -> Style["Mainland", Bold]
         |>
       |>
     |>];
```

The inheritance that I'm talking about is the properties that use `DefaultFunction` to compute their values. Besides the properties I also define three classes of counties, one for Alaska, one for Hawaii and one for the US mainland. The reason for this is that later I'll want to manipulate the three areas separately; I'll want to rescale and translate Alaska and Hawaii to the positions which they have in the map in the original post.

In order to be able to use the entity store you'll want to add it to `$EntityStores`:

```
AppendTo[$EntityStores, store]
```

I would also recommend adding as a resource object:

```
ro = ResourceObject[<|
    "Name" -> "USCounty",
    "ResourceType" -> "DataResource",
    "Content" -> store
    |>];
ResourceData[ro]; (* Needed to call this, otherwise the next line did not work. *)
ro["ResourceLocations"]
```

The advantage of this is that resource objects should be, I think, that they are persistent, i.e. next time you start up *Mathematica* you can get ahold of your data with

```
ResourceObject["USCounty"]
```

and add it to `$EntityStores` using

```
AppendTo[$EntityStores, ResourceObject["USCounty"]]
```

But right now this doesn't seem to work. It works within one session, but in a new session the resource object has disappeared. This feature as well is new in *Mathematica* 11. We can now do things like

```
EntityList["USCounty"] // Shallow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
EntityList@EntityClass["USCounty", "Hawaii"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Back to GeoRegionValuePlot

With the entity store in place we can now use `GeoRegionValuePlot` to plot our custom data like this:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[EntityList[EntityClass["USCounty", "Mainland"]] -> "Unemployment"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With a few options it looks almost the same as the image in the question:

```
getColor[val_] := Which[
  0 < val < 0.01667, RGBColor[{247, 251, 255}/255],
  0.0166 < val < 0.0333, RGBColor[{222, 235, 247}/255],
  0.0333 < val < 0.05, RGBColor[{198, 219, 239}/255],
  0.05 < val < 0.0666, RGBColor[{158, 202, 225}/255],
  0.0666 < val < 0.0833, RGBColor[{107, 174, 214}/255],
  0.0833 < val < 0.1, RGBColor[{66, 146, 198}/255],
  0.1 < val < 0.1166, RGBColor[{33, 113, 181}/255],
  0.1166 < val < 0.1333, RGBColor[{8, 81, 156}/255],
  0.1333 < val < 0.15, RGBColor[{8, 48, 107}/255],
  True, RGBColor[{8, 48, 107}/255]
  ]

GeoRegionValuePlot[
 EntityList[EntityClass["USCounty", "Mainland"]] -> "Unemployment",
 ColorFunction -> getColor,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotLegends -> None,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[None]],
 GeoBackground -> None,
 GeoProjection -> {
   "LambertAzimuthal",
   "Centering" -> GeoPosition[{30, -195/2}]
   },
 PlotRange -> {{-0.37, 0.38}, {-0.13, 0.38}},
 ImageSize -> 1000
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### The last details

The previous map still lacks the white borderlines, Hawaii, and Alaska. For Hawaii and Alaska we need to use `Inset`, so we have to use `GeoGraphics`. Hence, below is a `GeoGraphics` version of the previous plot.

```
getPolygon[entity_] := {
  GeoStyling[None],
  getColor[entity["Unemployment"]],
  Polygon[entity]
  }

alaska = GeoGraphics[
   getPolygon /@ EntityList[EntityClass["USCounty", "Alaska"]], 
   GeoBackground -> None];
hawaii = GeoGraphics[
   getPolygon /@ EntityList[EntityClass["USCounty", "Hawaii"]], 
   GeoBackground -> None];

map = GeoGraphics[{
    getPolygon /@ EntityList[EntityClass["USCounty", "Mainland"]],
    Inset[alaska, {-0.3, -0.06}, {0, 0}, 0.3],
    Inset[hawaii, {-0.15, -0.06}, {0.1569, -0.0436}, 0.3]
    },
   GeoBackground -> None,
   GeoProjection -> {
     "LambertAzimuthal",
     "Centering" -> GeoPosition[{30, -195/2}]
     },
   PlotRange -> {{-0.37, 0.38}, {-0.13, 0.38}},
   ImageSize -> 1000
   ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To add the borderlines I first make a black and white mask, where states are black and the background is white. The state borderlines that I want to draw are white as well; I then use `ImageAdd` to put the images together. The counties will be unaffected because we'll only be adding black to them, except for on the borderlines.

```
states = Cases[
   EntityList@Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Country" -> Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]}],
   Entity[_, {_, _}]
   ];

alaska = GeoGraphics[
   Polygon /@ EntityList[EntityClass["USCounty", "Alaska"]], 
   GeoBackground -> None];
hawaii = GeoGraphics[
   Polygon /@ EntityList[EntityClass["USCounty", "Hawaii"]], 
   GeoBackground -> None];

borders = GeoGraphics[{
    FaceForm[Black],
    EdgeForm[White],
    GeoStyling[None],
    Polygon /@ states,
    Inset[alaska, {-0.3, -0.06}, {0, 0}, 0.3],
    Inset[hawaii, {-0.15, -0.06}, {0.1569, -0.0436}, 0.3]
    },
   GeoBackground -> None,
   GeoProjection -> {
     "LambertAzimuthal",
     "Centering" -> GeoPosition[{30, -195/2}]
     },
   PlotRange -> {{-0.37, 0.38}, {-0.13, 0.38}},
   ImageSize -> 1000
   ];

ImageAdd[map, borders]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there an easy way to go from the Fips code to names and back?

Comment: @M.R. I don't understand what the situation you are thinking about is, the way I see it you have them both at the same time so you don't don't have to go from one to the other.

Comment: My situation is that I have a 2 column csv that contains (FIP, Value) pairs and I'd like to plot them but I don't know how to go from FIP to county in Mathematica's geo plots.

Comment: Trying to plot data in census blocks as well, I'll add some example data to the question.

Comment: see my updated question...

Comment: @M.R. I've added a discussion about using custom data together with entity stores to get the most out of `GeoRegionValuePlot` with custom data.

Comment: Well done! How'd you come up with `getColor`?

Comment: @J.M. I found the colors in the source code for the original image, and the thresholds could also be inferred approximately.

Comment: As of 10.4, `GeoGraphics` works with `Show`, so you can combine `GeoRegionValuePlot` with `GeoGraphics`.